GnuPG often asks for subkey passphrase when signing/encrypting messages even with large [default|max]-cache-ttl in gpg-agent.conf
I have in my ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf the following:
default-cache-ttl 172800
max-cache-ttl 172800

which works fine when I am en- or decrypting files using one of my regular GPG key pairs (just a public key and a private key). That is, no pinentry dialog is shown if the passphrase has been cached/used within the last 48 hours -- those 172,800 seconds from gpg-agent.conf).
The keys that I use for signing (S) and encrypting (E) e-mail messages consist of a public key, a primary private key (not stored on the machine for security purposes), and two secret subkeys  (S/E). Incidentally, these two subkeys use a different passphrase than the primary private key.
The problem is that when I am signing or encrypting e-mail messages using this different set of keys, the cache period seems to be significantly shorter. Specifically, the passphrase will not survive to the next day (i.e., <24 hrs. after the last use).
Is this normal? What parameter(s) can I add to my ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf to make GPG agent cache the subkey passphrase for a longer period?
Thanks.

Should anyone stumble upon this question, the cause of the problem turned out to be very simple. I am using Mutt, and I had in one of its configuration files the line set pgp_timeout = 86400 (i.e., "please cache the passphrase for 24 hours"; see the Mutt Manual).
